# Getting "TypeError: Unable to get property 'age' of undefined or null reference" when I try to run

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My app is simply supposed to increase the age (initialized to 20) or decrease the age if ADD button or SUBTRACT button is clicked, respectively.

I am not understanding why I keeping getting this error. I check in reducer.js to make sure to initialize the state with the 'age' property accordingly, so I am completely lost as to what might be causing this. I double checked that I had all the right dependencies, as well as made sure all the syntax is correct.

One other thing I think might be causing it is that I am not using the spread operator in my reducer.js for the line of code `const newState = {state}` . For some reason, vscode is not letting me use the spread operator. Everytime I do and run my app, nothing appears on screen. Is there a dependency that needs to be installed to use the spread operator?

The following is my code:

// index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';

import reducer from './reducer';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';

const store = createStore(reducer);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

// App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div>Age: <span>{this.props.age}</span></div>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAgeUp}>Add</button>
        <button onClick={this.props.onAgeDown}>Sub</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { age: state.age };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    onAgeUp: () => dispatch({ type: 'ADD' }),
    onAgeDown: () => dispatch({ type: 'SUBTRACT' })

  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

// reducer.js

```
import { ADD, SUBTRACT } from './actionTypes';

const initialState = {
  age: 20
};

const reducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
    const newState = {state};

    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD:
            newState.age+=1;
            break;
        case SUBTRACT:
            newState.age-=1;
            break;
        default:
            return state;
    }

};

export default reducer;
```

Comment: `const newState = {...state};` is equivalent to `const newState = Object.assign({}, state)` - both clone the original state. Now `newState` is an object  containing the initial state, i.e. `newState = { state: { age: 20 } }`

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix, You can use `Object.assign` instead of spread operator:

```
const newState = Object.assign({}, state);
```

---

For using spread operator you must check couple of things:

first make sure `@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread` dependency is in `package.json`, then add it to plugins of babel config file:

```
{
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread"]
}
```

for more info visit [babel rest spread](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread)

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems here:

- You're declaring newState as {state}. This creates object within object.
- Since you're declaring newState with const, it can not be changed. But you're trying to change newState in both of your case.
- You're not returning anything to the state. Main idea of the redux is to update the state by returning the new state.

Comment: properties of const objects can be changed, the object itself can not be reassigned

Comment: @daveyfaherty Thank you for pointing out. Can you please mention reference so that I can learn more about that?

Comment: Sure: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description

Answer (score 0):

newState looks like this the way you define it:

```
{
  state: {
    age: 20
  }
}
```

That's why age is undefined, it's not an immediate child property.

Eg:

```
const letters = { alpha: 'a' }

const spreadLetters = { letters }
```

spreadLetters will be a new object, with one property, "letters".
The value of this property will be an exact copy of the original letters variable.

```
{
  letters: {
    alpha: a
  }
}
```